# Why my api is not working as expected? error Invalid request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Why my api is not working as expected? error Invalid request i am testing my api in postman software but its not working its showing me error Invalid request can anyone tell whats the problem?

Backend:

```
router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user || !req.user.email || !req.body || !req.body.city) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid request' });
  }

  const city = req.body.city;
  const email = req.user.email;

  User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email }, { city: city }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
    res.json({ message: 'City saved successfully' });
  });
});
```

I am doing like this on post req:

```
{
  "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
  "city": "New York"
}
```

And also tried this on post req:

```
{
  "city": "New York"
}
```

Comment: The first if statement returns the error because it is specified there

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of your condition . req.user & req.user.email maybe for authenticated middleware . you must add middleware to your route or using this --->

```
router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body || !req.body.city) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid request' });
  }

  const city = req.body.city;
  const email = req.user.email;

  User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email }, { city: city }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
    res.json({ message: 'City saved successfully' });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try adding `console.log(req.user);` at the very top of your callback. What does it output? As he said, it's likely an issue with your middleware.

Comment: In the first if block, use the AND(&&) operator, instead of OR(||) Operator